# Core Data does not use my Mapping Model

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration

When I set the option 'NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption' to yes, the new model is setup using the old models data. However, it should be using my custom Mapping Model to update specific values.

For some reason it does not use this mapping model and I really need it to as some important data is not moved from one old entity to a new entity.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have same problem. Have you got any solution on it?